# Change numbers to random letter in SED

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, awk

Considering the following number: `145478`

I want to replace these numbers with random letters from `a to z`.

My attempt so far: `sed -r 's/[0-9]/[a-z]/g'`

It does not change the pattern to another pattern but exactly whatever I typed in the second place.

The result I got is: `[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]`

How do I make it into an actual pattern? In other words, how do I turn these numbers into random letter?

Answer (score 1):

Not an `awk` or `sed` solution, but I hope this helps anyway. Are the same numbers always supposed to be replaced by the same letters? If not:

```
perl -pe 's/[0-9]/chr 97+rand 26/eg' input.txt
```

If they are, then this is one solution:

```
perl -MList::Util=shuffle -M5';$x=join"",shuffle a..z' -pe 'eval"tr/0-9/$x/"' input.txt
```

*Update:* For shorter versions of the second one, see [this thread](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1229701).